# What are Cisco Devices?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, networking

I am doing CCNA online and not for a minute have I not failed to come acroos the statement 'Cisco Device'

What exactly are cisco devices ? Please don't tell me 'Devices that use Cisco iOS' 
Can you list practical example of Cisco devices ? Please don't say 'Router' cause there so many router brands and models

Comment: Cisco is a brand of devices, they make all sorts of networking equipment. If you want a list of all devices they produce, I suggest you take a look at their website, there's no point in listing them here.

Comment: Cisco is also what the first C in CCNA stand for...

Answer (score 3):

Cisco is a major manufacturer of routers, switches, firewalls, security appliances, VoIP gateways, phones, and various other devices used for networking and telecommunication - see https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/index.html